# Increasing Speed of Fuzzy Matching words on two lists

Tags: python

I have a list of about 500 items on one list. I'd like to replace all fuzzy-matched items in that list with the smallest length item.

Is there a way to speed up my implementation of fuzzy match?

Note: I posted a similar question before, but I'm reframing it due to lack of response.

My implementation:

```
def find_fuzzymatch_samelist(list1, list2, cutoff=90):
    """
    #list1 = list(ds1.Title)
    #list2 = list(ds1.Title)
    """
    matchdict = defaultdict(list)

    for i, u in enumerate(list1):

        for i1, u1 in enumerate(list2):

            #Since list orders are the same, this makes sure this isn't the same item.
            if i != i1:

                if fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio(u, u1) >= cutoff:
                    pair = (u, u1)

                    #Because there are potential duplicates, I have to make the key constant.
                    #Otherwise, putting list1 as the key will result in both duplicate items
                    #serving as the key. 

                    """
                    Potential problem:
                    • what if there are diffrent shortstr? 

                    """

                    shortstr = min(pair, key=len)
                    longstr = max(pair, key=len)     
                    matchdict[shortstr].append(longstr)
    return matchdict
```

Comment: Have you profiled the code? Where is the time being spent? If it is in `partial_token_sort`, there is not much to do. Also, which library is `fuzz`? I get 39 hits in pypi.

Comment: Each run of the forloop takes about .01 seconds. So it's the sheer number of combinations. the library is called fuzzywuzzy

Comment: And what is the ratio to the overall execution time? Are the loops adding significant overhead? Computing `shortstr`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you have installed [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/), that will give you a 4x speed up.

Optimising the loop and the dictionary access:

```
def find_fuzzymatch_samelist(list1, list2, cutoff=90):
    matchdict = dict()

    for i1, i2 in itertools.permutations(range(len(list1), repeat=2)

        u1 = list1[i1]
        u2 = list2[i2]

        if fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio(u, u1) >= cutoff:    
            shortstr = min(u1, u2, key=len)
            longstr = max(u1, u2, key=len)     
            matchdict.get(shortstr, list).append(longstr)
    return matchdict
```

This is as fast as it gets besides the fuzz call. If you read the source, you see that some preprocessing is done for each string, in every iteration. We can do it all at once:

```
def _asciionly(s):
    if PY3:
        return s.translate(translation_table)
    else:
        return s.translate(None, bad_chars)


def full_pre_process(s, force_ascii=False):
    s = _asciionly(s)
    # Keep only Letters and Numbres (see Unicode docs).
    string_out = StringProcessor.replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace(s)
    # Force into lowercase.
    string_out = StringProcessor.to_lower_case(string_out)
    # Remove leading and trailing whitespaces.
    string_out = StringProcessor.strip(string_out)

    out = ''.join(sorted(string_out))
    out.strip()
    return out


def find_fuzzymatch_samelist(list1, list2, cutoff=90):
    matchdict = dict()
    if list1 is not list2:
        list1 = [full_pre_process(each) for each in list1]
        list2 = [full_pre_process(each) for each in list2]
    else:
        # If you are comparing a list to itself, we don't want to overwrite content.
        list1 = [full_pre_process(each) for each in list1]
        list2 = list1

    for i1, i2 in itertools.permutations(range(len(list1), repeat=2)
        u1 = list1[i1]
        u2 = list2[i2]

        if fuzz.partial_ratio(u, u1) >= cutoff:
            pair = (u1, u2)

            shortstr = min(pair, key=len)
            longstr = max(pair, key=len)     
            matchdict.get(shortstr, list).append(longstr)
    return matchdict
```

Comment: I am curious, what is the speed up with your dataset?

Comment: i'll get back to you. i'm not on my computer right now.